# Is there a rule to know when to pronounce letter c as a "soft c" (s) or "hard c" (k)?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

Is there a rule that would help me to learn when to pronounce the letter c as an "s" sound or a "k" sound?

For example:
 - cat (kat)
 - center (sinter)

Are there any rules, or is it all memorization?

Comment: Do you mean *pronounce* rather than *spell*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean "pronounce" rather than spell, since it all depends on sounds, here are some simple rules to follow.

> "c" is pronounced like "k" when it is not immediately followed by the letters "e", "i" or "y"

Examples:

> Car, cat, cabin, curtail, curfew, curb, court, cool, mucus

---

> "c" is pronounced like "s" when it comes directly before "e" or "i" or "y".

Examples:

> city, cinch, certain, cyan, embrace, receive, dance

There are odd difficult words, like "soccer", where "double c" counts as a "k" sounds, and words like "muscle" where the "s" takes precedence, rendering the "c" unsounded.

Comment: Actually, the edit belongs to @user4812 – [that user](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/18300/revisions) suggested adding the "y"; I merely added an extra word in the examples.

Comment: Well the answer seems to make sense, but using "cyan" spoiled it, in "cyan" 'c' does take the pronunciation of 'k', I guess there is an exception to every rule.

Comment: No it doesn't. "Cyan" is pronounced with an "s" sound.

Comment: How about _ocean_?

Answer (score 1):

Celtic is nowadays pronounced like Keltic, even though before the 19th Century the pronunciation like *Seltic was considered standard. Same for Celt. Other less well-known exceptions include ceilidh (pronounced similar to Kayleigh), cistvaen, Cymric and Cymru, a number of words ending in -c suffixed with a suffix starting in -e- or -i-, sceptic, sceptical, scepsis, scepticism, ASCII, loci (also pronounced, weirdly, considering it's the plural of locus, with s), cepstrum and centum (in centum and satem). Spot the exceptional c in supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.

I also think the double-c rule isn't really a rule. What about success, flaccid or cappuccino?

And the inverse also sometimes occurs. If people forget the cedilla on açai, façade or limaçon, you get a c before a or o that's pronounced like s. Also think about c before ae or oe when these are pronounced as if an e. CMOS is pronounced like See-moss, not as *KMOS. The pronunciations of lac when it's an abbreviation of laceration and soc when it's an abbreviation of social, socialite or sociology end in an s sound.